# Embeded map/image in gtk glade

Tags: gtk, glade

I have a gnome-builder project building GUI by Glade. Now I have an embedded map url like  this:

```
<iframe src="https://api.ncovtrack.com/covid/vietnam/provinces?metric=cases&showTable=false&showMap=true" title="ncovtrack - COVID & Vaccination Statistics" height='500' width='928'></iframe>
```

I want to find sth like (img src="") in HTML but I can't find the same thing in Glade? Could anyone help me pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WebKitGTK](https://webkitgtk.org/). You can add `WebKitWebView` in glade. Below is an example in python.

### demo.py

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("WebKit2", "4.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2, GObject

builder = Gtk.Builder()
GObject.type_ensure(WebKit2.WebView)
builder.add_from_file("web.glade")

webview = builder.get_object("webview")
uri = "https://api.ncovtrack.com/covid/vietnam/provinces?metric=cases&showTable=false&showMap=true"
webview.load_uri(uri)

window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.show_all()

window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

Gtk.main()
```

### web.glade

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <requires lib="webkit2gtk" version="2.28"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="default-width">600</property>
    <property name="default-height">900</property>
    <child>
      <object class="WebKitWebView" type-func="webkit_web_view_get_type" id="webview">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">True</property>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Great! Tks a lot. I appreciate it

Comment: Can we remove the last line "Statistics Provided by ncovtrack.com" :v
I just want to create a local Ubuntu app for my homework

Comment: @ĐỗQuangHuy You can run custom javascript in webkit2, see https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/WebKit2-4.0/classes/WebView.html#WebKit2.WebView.run_javascript_in_world. Then you can hide a element with javascript.

Comment: Tks a lot John. It helps me a lot

Comment: Sorry again @John, I tried few times with run_js_in_world but I can't make it work. 
Could you give me an example of using this Webkit2 function